# How to get the path of an XML document

Tags: windows-phone

In my project there is an XML document. I saved it in a folder named "XML". How can I get the path of the XML file, so that I have to parse the XML document?

I tried using the code below, but it doesn't work. What is the solution?

```
String str="Myproject;component/XML/myxml.xml "
```

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the **Build Action** is set to `Content` and you should be able to reference it directly without needing to qualify with the assemblyname/namespace.

This works for me:

```
var str = "XML/myxml.xml";

var xdoc = XDocument.Load(str);
```

Comment: I tried this code but doesnt works.I got the output as /XML/myxml.xml

Comment: @Sujiz what do you mean you got that as the output?

Comment: @Sujiz try removing the starting forward slash.

Comment: is there any method to convert var to string?

Comment: @Sujiz the compiler resolves `var`'s at compile time. You can set the type explicitly if you wish. In the above example `str` is a `string` and `xdoc` an `XDocument`.